# Wordpress Permalinks never work on localhost Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, ubuntu-12.10

Wordpress permalinks aren't working, except for the default. How do I enable this rewriting? I've tried:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo service apache2 restart
```

The permalinks are saving to the .htaccess in /localhost/wordpress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and I copy to root /var/www just to try, and it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had also tried the AllowOverwride All, but it was in the wrong config file and it broke. (Correct file to add this to is /etc/apache2/sites-available/default) [This](http://mixeduperic.com/ubuntu/5-simple-steps-to-configure-wordpress-to-use-permalinks-on-an-ubuntu-server.html) had the solution for me.

**Update for 13.10**

On a new install, I got it working as described above, but with the following changes:

Instead of editing /etc/apache2/sites-available/default as they describe, you must use:

`sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

and add the following after the `DocumentRoot /var/www` line:

```
<Directory /var/www>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

As the tutorial describes, run `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Set up the /var/www/.htaccess file, and run:

```
sudo chmod 664 /var/www/.htaccess

sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/.htaccess
```

And restart with `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: just added a description with a few changes, seems that tutorial is a bit old and not completely working for latest Ubuntu